# Apache service start inactive in chef recipe on Linux Red Hat

Tags: ruby, linux, apache, chef-infra

I have a customer who has 500 web sites on server, and I am trying to automate it. Sometimes when he wants to deploy configurations on the server Apache wont start even Syntax is Ok, because I'm checking it before new start of the server.
This is workflow of execution recipes:

- Stop the server
- Download configurations
- Copy configurations(all 500)
- Check error_log(apachectl configtest)
- (if Syntax Ok) Start the server

and the problem starts here because my service for start the server is inactive.

```
Executing /bin/systemctl is-active httpd
 ---- Begin output of /bin/systemctl is-active httpd ----
 DEBUG: STDOUT: inactive
DEBUG: STDERR: 
 ---- End output of /bin/systemctl is-active httpd ----
DEBUG: Ran /bin/systemctl is-active httpd returned 3
DEBUG: Executing /bin/systemctl is-enabled httpd
DEBUG: ---- Begin output of /bin/systemctl is-enabled httpd ----
DEBUG: STDOUT: enabled
DEBUG: STDERR: 
DEBUG: ---- End output of /bin/systemctl is-enabled httpd ----
DEBUG: Ran /bin/systemctl is-enabled httpd returned 0
DEBUG: Executing /bin/systemctl start httpd
DEBUG: ---- Begin output of /bin/systemctl start httpd ----
DEBUG: STDOUT: 
DEBUG: STDERR: Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
DEBUG: ---- End output of /bin/systemctl start httpd ----
DEBUG: Ran /bin/systemctl start httpd returned 1
```

Maybe someone knows how to activate service again?

```
service 'httpd' do
  supports :status => true
  action :start
  ignore_failure true
end
```

I emphasize this is not happening every time.

Comment: Usually we can pass multiple actions as an array. So, you can have something like `action [ :enable, :start ]`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I found out that there was problem with syncing with buffer and data on disc, now I will try to add command:
 
execute 'synchronize data' do
  command 'sync'
end
before starting the service, to see if it helps.